# Range of a function: countable or not?

Tags: real-analysis

Would it be wrong to argue that if one considers a countable set $A$ and a real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then the range of $f$ on $A$, that is the set $f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$, is countable?

Comment: it's obviously correct.

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/144751.